# Change a txt column to a date column in R using its index position

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to change a txt column that has a date in the format %m/%d/%Y to a date but the problem is that I cannot use its name because its not known (I am doing an app so the name can vary), one thing that I am sure is that is the column number 1 of the dataframe.

using the name of the column the R code would be

```
dates <- as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

But I cant do this, I need to use the index so I tried this

```
dates <- as.Date(data[1], "%m/%d/%Y")
```

But I get this error

```
Error in as.Date.default(data[1], "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'data[1]' to class “Date”
```

thanks for the help

Comment: `data[[1]]` - you need to grab the vector not the list. `[[` is analogous to `$`

Comment: `data[, 1]` will also work. Look at `str(data[1]`, `str(data[[1]]`, and `str(data[ , 1]`. The first one returns a data frame, the second and third ones a vector.

Comment: @dcarlson - unless you're working with a tibble, then you get a tibble back with the `data[,1]` version.